# Android user registration in firebase using authnetication and it should display that data in realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

1 You have to design 2 screens.
a) Registration screen
b) Dashboard screen
2) Registration screen should contain below fields:
a) First Name
b) Last Name
c) Email
d) Mobile Number
e) Password
f) Confirm Password

3. Registration Form should have
   standard validation like:

a) User can enter max 50 characters for First Name
b) User can enter max 100 characters for Last Name
c) Email standard validation (xx@xx.xx)
d) Password should be in hidden
e) Users can enter max 20 characters for Passwords.
4) Registration screen records should be inserted into the Firebase Realtime Database.
5) After submitting a record on the Registration screen, the user should redirect to the
Dashboard screen.
6) On Dashboard Screen, Get all the users data from database and display list of users.

I have done the authentication is working fine but not showing in realtime database.

Comment: Show us the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: If you're new to Android development, then I think that this article, [How to create a clean Firebase authentication using MVVM?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) might help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you add this data to real-time Database if not then first add that data using model like UserModel(). Than use that code to insert it into realtime database

```
DatabaseReference  mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Here is user model

```
public class User {

public String username;
public String email;

public User() {
    
}

public User(String username, String email) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

Than use this code to insert it into real time db

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
```

Go to firebase real-time db and check is you data inserted. if inserted than use that code to read data

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
    }
    else {
        Log.d("firebase", String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue()));
    }
}
```

});